# Is it possible to copy a value in the clipboard of the user and redirect him to another web page via the same button

Tags: javascript, html

For a project I'm trying to create a button that has 2 goals :
-1Copy a value in the clipboard of the user
-2Redirect the user to another url

I found a way to make both seperatly but I'm not able to find a way to do both at the same time

Here is the html code I'm using :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="hidden" value={{t}} id="myInput">
<p></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Home</button>
<script>

function myFunction() {
  // Get the text field
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  // Select the text field
  copyText.select();


  // Copy the text inside the text field
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  // Redirect to my other website
  window.open("my_other_website", "_blank");


}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I comment the line " window.open" myinput gets in the user clipboard but unforunatly if I leave the "window.open" the redirection is made but without the value in the clipboard...

If anyone has solution about this thank's in advance...

Comment: Technically there is no redirection; you're opening a new tab. How do you *know* that the copying has failed in the next page?

Comment: The word " redirection" might not be the good one. I want the user to get in its cliboard a token and then to open the tab of another website with just one click on one button. I know that copying has failed cause when I try this code on dev environnement it just doesn't work unfortunately. It seems like you can't change the client clipboard ANDopen a new tab at the same time ( maybe for security reasons ?)

Comment: I see. And when the new tab opens, do you want it to automatically paste the copied value? Do note that the `writeText` method of the `clipboard` object returns a `Promise`. That means that it allows other code to run while it is copying the values to the clipboard. The Clipboard API also needs explicit input from the user, otherwise it won't work. Alternatively you could send the value from the input with the URL of your new page as a parameter: `my_other_website?token=12345` and then read the token from the URL in your new page.

Comment: Actually I'm working on a very specific thing so the alternative with the token in the URL doesn't work unfortunately... The user will click on the link, it will open the tap and just he will just have to CRTL-V the token. I also tried to put a little sleep function (1second) between the writeText and the window open but it doesn't change anything. It's actually very weird, I don't understand the conflict here... Maybe I should check the permissions of the browser, there migtht be something blocking the action of modifying the clipboard AND opening a new tab.